# Two input fields refer to one event.target.value in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two input fields and they refer to the same event.target.value object. I want to have them separatly.

```
  <form
    class="flex-list"
    [formGroup]="calculation_Input"
    (input)="input($event)"
  >
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="slider3"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>

    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="slider3"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

The event.target.value refers now to both inputs and I have no clue how I can change it.

```
  input(e: any): void {
console.log(event.target.value)
  }
```

Comment: You could try giving them different IDs, the `id` attribute value must be unique in a page. `event.target` will be the element that triggered the event, is not clear what you mean by "the event.target.value refers now to both inputs".

Comment: I tried unfortunatly it returns an emty object, no clue if its because of angular

Comment: Two inputs work separately.. the console logs different values. What exactly you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<form
    class="flex-list"
    [formGroup]="calculation_Input"
    (input)="input(&event)"
  
  >
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="slider3"
        name="in1"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>

    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="slider3"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        name="in2"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

event call :

```
input(e: any): void {
  if(e.target.name == "in1")
    console.log("for fist input value is : " + event.target.value)
  else console.log("for second input value is : " + event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: I need to have the input function globally that it refers to all other fields.

Comment: you can set a name for each input , and use event.target.name to know wich one haldle the event .

Comment: example: `<input name="input1"><input name="input2"> , in your ts , use , if(event.target.name === "input1"){ Now you use input 1 event call "} else { in input2 event call }`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [formControl] attribute on each of the inputs and then you can use valueChanges and subscribe.

```
<form
    class="flex-list"
    [formGroup]="calculation_Input"
  >
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="inputRangeStart"
        [formControl]="inputRangeStart"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>

    <div class="range-slider">
      <input
        id="inputRangeEnd"
        class="range-slider__range"
        type="range"
        [formControl]="inputRangeEnd"
        value.equity="equity"
        min="0"
        max="500"
      />
      <span class="range-slider__value"> 0</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Event Call: // some.component.ts

```
inputRangeStart = new FormControl();
inputRangeEnd = new FormControl();

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.inputRangeStart.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.onInput(value))
 this.inputRangeEnd.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.onInput(value))
}
onInput(value: string){
    // do something
}
```